# ¿Cómo reemplazar los missing values de una columna con el valor de la media del resto, agrupada por 2 variables?

Tags: r

He realizado este código, sin embargo cuando compruebo si existen NAs me siguen apareciendo. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Numberofpeople es de tipo numérico.

```
df1 <- df
df1%>%
  group_by(Districts, Month) %>%
  mutate(Numberofpeople = if_else(is.na(Numberofpeople), mean(Numberofpeople, na.rm = T), Numberofpeople))
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionar:

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(Districts, Month) %>%
    mutate(Numberofpeople = ifelse(is.na(Numberofpeople),
                                   mean(Numberofpeople, na.rm=TRUE),
                                   Numberofpeople)
    ) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Observaciones

- Reemplace el `if_else()` por el `ifelse()`base, esto por que la versión de `dplyr` es estricta en cuanto a los valores a retornar, ambos deben ser del mismo tipo, si `Numberofpeople` llegara a ser un `ìnteger` (algo factible) y como la media es un `double` te daría un error.
- El `ungroup()` final es para retornar un `dataframe` similar al original y no la versión agrupada